# R - plotted data points are indistinguishable

Tags: r, math, plot, rstudio

```
W = c(20000, 5000, 3000, 8, 2, 0.5)
BMR = c(19000, 12000, 960, 86, 30, 10)
BMRPlot <- plot(W, BMR, main='Graph 2', cex=1.25, pch=21, bg='blue', lwd=1)
```

The above is the data I am trying to plot, however as you can probably tell the final data points once plotted appear to be indistinguishable as they are so close together. What could I add to my line of code that would change the view of this so that all points could be visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a situation like this, you more or less have to use a transformation to make all the points visible.  Otherwise, the points would have to be incredibly small not to overlap, and then you wouldn't be able to see them.

A log transformation of x and y seems to work here.

```
logW = log(c(20000, 5000, 3000, 8, 2, 0.5))
logBMR = log(c(19000, 12000, 960, 86, 30, 10))
BMRPlot <- plot(logW, logBMR, main='Graph 2', cex=1.25, pch=21, bg='blue', lwd=1)
```

[image]

As noted by commenter below, you can do the log-transform within the plot statement if you want your tick values to be untransformed:

```
W = c(20000, 5000, 3000, 8, 2, 0.5)
BMR = c(19000, 12000, 960, 86, 30, 10)
BMRPlot <- plot(W, BMR, main='Graph 2', cex=1.25, pch=21, bg='blue', lwd=1, log="xy")
```

[image]

Comment: You don't need to log the original data. You can do `plot(W, BMR, log="x", las=1)` (to log just the x-axis) or `plot(W, BMR, log="xy", las=1)` to log both axes. Also, this way you get the actual value labels on the axes, rather than their logs.

Comment: You certainly don't need to.  Just a matter of preference/circumstance.